# Buildx Docker Image Claims to be a Manifest List

Tags: docker, manifest, multiplatform, buildx

I'm trying create a Docker manifest in order to create a multi-platform image `my-repo/my-image:<some-tag>` on Dockerhub. Building for both platforms at once does not work since the Dockerfile expects a mounted tarball of compiled binaries. Also note that I'm using a AMD64 VM in a GitHub Actions CI, so I have to cross-compile to ARM64.

To build I use something like this:

```bash
# Build & push for ARM64; using registry cache since this takes forever to build
docker buildx build . \
    --tag my-repo/my-image-arm64:<some-tag> \
    --platform=linux/arm64 \
    --output type=registry \
    --build-arg tarball_uri=<link-to-arm64-tarball> \
    --cache-to type=registry,ref=my-repo/my-image-cache,mode=max \
    --cache-from type=registry,ref=my-repo/my-image-cache,mode=max

# Build & push for AMD64; a more conventional build
docker buildx build . \
    --tag my-repo/my-image-amd64:<some-tag> \
    --build-arg tarball_uri=<link-to-amd64-tarball>
docker push my-repo/my-image-amd64:<some-tag>
```

When I then however run the following command:

```bash
docker manifest create my-repo/image-name:<some-tag> \
    my-repo/my-image-amd64:<some-tag> \
    my-repo/my-image-arm64:<some-tag>
```

I get the error message

`docker.io/my-repo/my-image-arm64:<some-tag> is a manifest list`, **only for the ARM64 image**. Generally, a manifest list is created, but without the `my-repo/my-image-arm64:<some-tag>` manifest.

Assuming `my-repo/my-image-arm64:<some-tag>` is now actually a manifest list, I do

```bash
docker manifest inspect my-repo/my-image-arm64:<some-tag>
```

but then get

```bash
no such manifest: docker.io/my-repo/my-image-arm64:<some-tag>
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi, were u able to find a solution to this? I am running into the exact same error. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, at least found a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

So an alternative solution to using `docker manifest`, is running the following, assuming that both `my-repo/my-image-arm64:latest` and `my-repo/my-image-amd64:latest` have been pushed to your registry:

```bash
docker buildx imagetools create -t my-repo/my-image:latest \
    my-repo/my-image-arm64:latest \
    my-repo/my-image-amd64:latest
```

This will also automatically push the new multi-platform image to your registry (e.g. Dockerhub).

Comment: Seems to be working. However, I cannot run docker manifest on the final image i.e `my-repo/my-image:latest` in your example. The docker pull command does pull architecture specific image, but the lack of manifest is a little concerning. Running `docker inspect <my-repo/my-image:latest>` shows the correct arch after pulling the image.

Comment: Yep, this solution completely disregards the usage of manifests. All I can say is that my multi-platform image works on both platforms.

Comment: My guess is that recent releases of Docker Engine broke undocumented behavior for `manifest`.  It's listed as experimental and subject to that sort of thing.

Answer (score 4):

## Attention! - Real Solution provided below

When using buildx and applying the `--platform` flag followed by your target architecture, buildx will automatically create a manifest list for the image even if we only specify one architecture. To verify this, you can use the `docker manifest inspect` command against your image you just created and will see something similar to this:

```
{
   "schemaVersion": 2,
   "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json",
   "manifests": [
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json",
         "size": 1059,
         "digest": "sha256:7f79d684251feb3981eac2b295fecda741c3a1d743bdf0ba6256254b06ad0ce3",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "amd64",
            "os": "linux"
         }
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json",
         "size": 566,
         "digest": "sha256:0825f2a2d968c80f06fbc91f1d1c1cf46a4049186fa33bb00507943d5f0b136a",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "unknown",
            "os": "unknown"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

### Work-around Solution

With the new versions of docker engine, we have these new flags called `--provenance` and `--sbom` that we didn't have before. Setting these to `--provenance false` and/or `--sbom false` while building an architecture specific image or a multi-arch image with buildx, setting these flags to `false` will fix the problem however, we are disabling the amazing functionality these two attestations provide us. Down below you will see the process for the work-around.

Ex:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64 --provenance false -t <registry-url>/<image-name>-arm64:<image-tag> -f <path/to/dockerfile> . --push
```

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 --provenance false -t <registry-url>/<image-name>-amd64:<image-tag> -f <path/to/dockerfile> . --push
```

```
docker manifest create <registry-url>/<image-name>:latest \
<registry-url>/<image-name>-arm64:<image-tag> \
<registry-url>/<image-name>-amd64:<image-tag>
```

```
docker manifest push <registry-url>/<image-name>:latest
```

### Real Solution

The reason these issues are here in the first place is the fact that you are using the legacy `default` image store which doesn't support multi-architecture images or the `provenance` and `sbom` attestations. In order to fix these issues once and for all, follow the official docker documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/containerd/) that tells you how to enable the `containerd` image store and restart the docker daemon service.

Doing this will allow you to create multi-arch images locally, and capitalize on the `provenance`/`sbom` attestations defined [here](https://docs.docker.com/build/attestations/).

Comment: Thank you for sharing the `--provenance false` flag, this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
        name: Create manifest list and push
        working-directory: /tmp/digests
        run: |
          docker buildx imagetools create $(jq -cr '.target."docker-metadata-action".tags | map(select(startswith("${{ env.REGISTRY_IMAGE }}")) | "-t " + .) | join(" ")' /tmp/bake-meta.json) \
            $(printf '${{ env.REGISTRY_IMAGE }}@sha256:%s ' *)          
      -
```

You can check here

https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/multi-platform/#distribute-build-across-multiple-runners